# Unexpected token using babel loader and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I was studying React, and i have a problem with my babel-loader, when I try to use the command `yarn webpack-dev-server --mode development`, it shows this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import React from "react";
| import { render } from "react-dom";
> render(<h1>Hello World</h1>,document.getElementById("App"))
| 
|
```

The bundle.js its right,i used the `babel src/index.js -o public/bundle.js` to transpile the code

My webpack.config

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My babel config

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react'
    ],
};
```

my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
 render(<h1>Hello World</h1>,document.getElementById("App"))
```

I was expecting to run the webpack